# Saving var using JavaScript and redirecting to URL

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a very simple web form containing two input fields and a submit button.

What I would like to do is save the two strings inserted and redirect to my other HTML file (which is in the same folder).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Players enter</title>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ticTac.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=styleSheet.css></link>

</head>
<body>
 <form >
      player one name: <input type="text" id="firstname"><br>
      player two name: <input type="text" id="secondname"><br>
      <input type="submit" onclick="checkNames();"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function checkNames(){
    var nameOne = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var nameTwo = document.getElementById("secondname").value;
    //window.location.href = 'C:\Users\x\Desktop\hw3\tic\Game.html';
    //window.location.replace("C:\Users\x\Desktop\hw3\tic\Game.html");
    window.location.assign("C:\Users\x\Desktop\hw3\tic\Game.html");
}
```

I have commented the two other options I tried which also do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an HTML form... this means that your submit button will fire and try to submit your form.

In order to prevent this, you need to prevent that event from triggering. A simple modification to your JavaScript function should do the trick.

```js
function checkNames() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var nameOne = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var nameTwo = document.getElementById("secondname").value;
    window.location.href = 'SOME-PATH/Game.html';
}
```

Comment: Since the file is "in the same folder" - use `window.location.href = "Game.html";`

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to a page in your computer you can use:

```
window.location.href = 'file:///C:/Users/x/Desktop/hw3/tic/Game.html';
```

There are more than one way of passing the values to another page. Here is an example using query string.

In the page that has the values.

```
var q = '?nameOne=' + encodeURI(nameOne) + '&nameTwo=' + encodeURI(nameTwo)
window.location.href = 'file:///C:/Users/x/Desktop/hw3/tic/Game.html' + q;
```

In the page receiving the values.

```
var nameOne = location.search.slice(1).split("&")[0].split("=")[1];
var nameTwo = location.search.slice(1).split("&")[1].split("=")[1];
```

Comment: I made a mistake, I used \ instead of /. Did you try with /?

Comment: When you open your page, what does appear on the address bar?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/vlad/Desktop/hw3/tic/playerEnter.html

Comment: Are you replacing x by vlad?

Comment: yep thats my windows username, the problem was that its a form in my html, so  event.preventDefault(); fixed this issue

Answer (score 0):

Use 
     window.location="url";